# Removing 'angular2-datatable' caused RxJS errors to appear

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am upgrading Angular 8 to Angular 10 and while doing so removed [angular2-datatable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-datatable). Problem is as soon I remove it I get following errors:

```
Property 'takeUntil' does not exist on type 'Observable<any>'
```

This makes sense as Angular 10 needs RxJS 6.5.3+. But as soon as I bring `angular2-datatable` back, above errors disappear. I am confused about what is causing this behaviour. The only thing I found relevant is `angular2-datatable` has added `rxjs: ^5.0-beta` as a peer dependency, but not sure how it's making things work.

Any thoughts to help understand this behaviour are appreciated.

Comment: rxjs 6 has a lot of breaking changes, versions above and below are kinda incompatible.

Comment: Do not upgrade between more than 1 major version. It will help you track down problems to 1 version, instead of 2. You should also always update your dependencies when updating `@angular/core` as there's most likely breaking changes.